# JSRender: How do you compare a variable in an if statement?

Tags: jquery, jsrender

My question is probably pretty basic, but how do you compare a variable you set to a value?

```
{{setvar "currentDate" 0 /}}

{{for Data}}
    {{if :~getvar("currentDate") > 5}}
        <div style="background-color: #000; color: #FFF;">currentDate:{{:~getvar("currentDate")}}</div>
    {{/if}}

    <div>
        <h1>{{>Name}}</h1>
        <h2>{{>~date(StartTime, "")}} - {{>~date(EndTime, "")}}</h2>
        <p>{{>Location}}: {{>Link}}</p>
    </div>

    {{:~increment("currentDate")}}
{{/for}}
```

If someone could help me out, I'd be very appreciative.

Thanks!

-Eric

Comment: Hmm... Figures. I kept playing around and came up with this: "{{if ~getvar("currentDate") != ~dayOfMonth(StartTime, "")}}". It seems to work. Is there a reference to the symbols (:, ~, etc)? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would probably handle that through a helper;

In your JS before you render the template:

```
views.helpers({
        curDate: function(increment) {
                  var ret = 0;
                  return inc ? ++ret : ret;
                }
    });
```

And change your template like so;

```
{{if ~curDate() > 5}}
```

and

```
{{:~curDate(true)}}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's an edit for the previous answer, you should write the ret variable before your function like below. Otherwise ret will stuck to 0 or 1 for return value :

```
var ret = 0;
views.helpers({
        curDate: function(increment) {
                  return inc ? ++ret : ret;
                }
    });
```